# C# - Filtering an ObservableCollection via subfield

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I have the following code:

```
SubjectsToChooseFrom = new ObservableCollection<SubjectDTO>(_model.Subjects);
SubjectsToChooseFrom = SubjectsToChooseFrom.Where(x => x.Id == (int)CurrentProgId);
```

`SubjectsToChooseFrom` is bound to a `ComboBox`. After this, only one element gets shown in the box instead of a list. Why is this, and how can I make sure all the values where `x.Id == (int)CurrentProgId` stay in `SubjectsToChooseFrom`?

**UPDATE**

XAML and code as requested:

```
<ComboBox Text="Choose program" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SubjectsToChooseFrom}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentSubjectId, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectedValuePath="Id"
    DisplayMemberPath="SubjectName">
</ComboBox>
```

Declaration:

```
private IEnumerable<SubjectDTO> _subjectsToChooseFrom;
public IEnumerable<SubjectDTO> SubjectsToChooseFrom
{
    get
    {
        return _subjectsToChooseFrom;
    }
    set
    {
        _subjectsToChooseFrom = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but are you sure the collection contains more than one element? I cannot see any problem in your code

Comment: Ues, I made sure via debugging. After the first line, it has 13 elements, and it should hold about 5 after filtering.

Comment: Can you paste the XAML code, please? Maybe the problem is there...

Comment: If you debug step by step and you jump over the second line (SubjectsToChooseFrom = SubjectsToChooseFrom.Where(x => x.Id == (int)CurrentProgId);), does it show the 13 elements? If so, can you please paste the SubjectsToChooseFrom declaration?

Comment: Do you realise that the SubjectsToChooseFrom variable is no longer an ObservableCollection after you use the Where method? You are replacing the value with a deferred execution Linq query?

Comment: @CarlosAdrián I fI jump over the second line, it does show the whole unfiltered list with 13 elements. If I use `Where`, it only shows 1.

Comment: @GlenThomas I'm not sure what that implies. Can you guide me towards a working filtering solution?

Comment: By the way, are you sure you have 5 records with the same Id? If you filter by Id the normal behaviour is to get just one record...

Comment: If you are sure you have 5 records, this should do the trick: SubjectsToChooseFrom = new ObservableCollection<SubjectDTO>(_model.Subjects).Where(x => x.Id == (int)CurrentProgId);

Comment: I would like to give a better answer than the one you have posted, however, for me it's completely unclear: _(a)_ why you wish to use `ObservableCollection<T>` _(b)_ how your model is build up _(c)_ what kind of workflow you envision from your app, eg: were would changes occur in your application, how is your model interacting with your views, which patterns are you using _(d)_ from the code you have shown, there seems to be nothing waranting an `ObservableCollection<T>` simply because you seem to re-assign at every change

Answer (score 0):

`Where` returns an `IQueryable`. You need to use `ToList()` or `ToArray()` etc. to materialize the results of this query.

If you're using MVVM, much better is to expose both your collections as public properties and raise `PropertyChanged` whenever these collections change for any reason. You can then bind your ComboBoxes to these properties and they'll automatically get updated.

Comment: `ToList()` does nothing, I still onlt get one item returned. I am binding the combobox to a property, and I'm trying to update it accordingly. I have 2 comboboxes, changing the value of one should filter the list of the other (I'm trying to achieve this filtering with `Where`).

Comment: @lte__: But looking a the first two lines of code you posted, you appear to be assigning it to the same variable both times.

Comment: I've tried this, too, with the same outcome:
                `SubjectsToChooseFrom = new ObservableCollection<SubjectDTO>(_model.Subjects);`
                `IEnumerable<SubjectDTO> temp = SubjectsToChooseFrom.Where(x => x.Id == (int)CurrentProgId).ToList();`
                `SubjectsToChooseFrom = temp;`

Comment: @lte__: Can you try this instead? `SubjectsToChooseFrom = new ObservableCollection<SubjectDTO>(_model.Subjects.Where(x => x.Id == (int)CurrentProgId));`

Answer (score -2):

I ended up doing this by hand:

```
await _model.LoadAsync();
SubjectsToChooseFrom = new ObservableCollection<SubjectDTO>(_model.Subjects);
ObservableCollection<SubjectDTO> temp = new ObservableCollection<SubjectDTO>();
foreach (var subject in SubjectsToChooseFrom) {
    if(subject.ProgId == CurrentProgId)
    {
        temp.Add(subject);
    }
}
SubjectsToChooseFrom = temp;
```

Comment: That's simply not the good way, any updates on the background will simply not come. There is absolutely no advantage of having your ObservableCollections either

Comment: Can you please suggest a better option?

Comment: I think it is a very bad solution. Please, consider the other ones before accepting this as a good one. It is bad for performance reasons, and also bad because it complicates the understanding. Try something like this better: SubjectsToChooseFrom = new ObservableCollection<SubjectDTO>(_model.Subjects.Where(x => x.Id == (int)CurrentProgId));